# Granting permissions for ADB deployed applications in Android

Tags: android, browser, permissions

I'm trying to create an Android application that reads the list of bookmarks from the built in Browser app. To access the ContentProvider, I need to have the `com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS` permission.

I'm deploying my application directly to my device using ADB. How do I grant this application the permission that I require?

Comment: Won't it automatically get the permisssions you specify in the manifest if you install it with ADB?

Comment: It is ADB, not ADK... ADK is the new accessory development kit... Big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set it in the androidmanifest.xml file.

Like so:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
```

This can be set in the Eclipse ADT Plugin with the following steps:

1. Select the application's manifest.
2. Go to the 'Permissions' tab.
3. Click 'Add', and chose 'Uses Permission'.
4. Enter the name of the permission, either by inputting the text or selecting the permission from the drop-down menu.

Comment: And how do you set this using the Eclipse Manifest editing GUI? I tried a few fields in there and they didn't add this string. Thanks.

Comment: I'd say: press the tab (in the bottom) for the xml version. Look at this example for the location: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/AndroidManifest.html

Comment: Found the solution on http://androidbook.blogspot.com/2010/10/reader-feedback-manifest-permissions.html, and edited it into the answer. Cheers!

Comment: Check!. But i'd still say you want to look at the XML tab, just to see how the file actually looks :)